# What approaches are advocated for a greater Mongolia given that ethnic Mongols might be a minority?

Tags: international-relations, secession, mongolia

I've heard about pan-Mongolism from time to time, such as this facebook post from [Mongolia Live](https://www.facebook.com/mongolialive.org/posts/2147780775283727), and there's a [Wikipedia article on it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan-Mongolism).

Assuming that Russia and China were willing to give up that land (after all, they aren't very nationalistic, aggressive in seeking and retaining territory, have powerful armies, nor are they ruthless towards minorities), I don't see how it'd work from a demographics perspective.

[Inner Mongolia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_Mongolia#Demographics) in China has ethnic Mongols in the minority. Unless I've done my sums wrong, if the areas in Inner Mongolia, present-day Mongolia, plus the Mongolian parts of Russia were combined (one possible pan-Mongolian state mentioned in the Wikipedia article), Han Chinese would form a majority, leaving ethnic Mongols in a minority: Inner Mongolia had 19,650,687 Han Chinese out of 24,706,321, [Tuva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuva) has a total population of 307,930, the [Altay Republic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altai_Republic) has a total population of 206,168, [Buryatia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buryatia#Ethnic_groups) has a total population of 972,021, and present day Mongolia has a total population of 3,081,677.

As far as I can tell, it's not possible to be one state, predominantly controlled by ethnic Mongols, and democratic. (Kind of like John Kerry's [comments about Israel](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/14194/what-did-kerry-mean-with-israel-can-either-be-jewish-or-democratic-it-cannot)) What approaches have present-day pan-Mongolians advocated for this demographic issue?

Comment: Note: Some approaches to this issue would be grossly morally reprehensible, and illegal under international law. Asking this question is not meant as an endorsement of those approaches.

Comment: Is there any evidence they care about being "democratic"? Last I checked, the original "greater Mongolia" wasn't very big on democracy.

Comment: @user4012 I’m not aware of Mongol privilege existing in the Mongol empire, but I’ll have to check. Serious answer: modern day Mongolia, the status quo, is a democracy, and gives minorities equal legal rights.

Comment: Please tell me that the part about _nationalistic, aggressive, and ruthless_  is sarcasm.

Comment: @pipe it comes after "Assuming that Russia and China were willing to give up that land", which is approximately as likely as "Assuming we have flying pigs"